# What do these latitudinal and longitudinal lines and accompanying hours and degrees represent?

Tags: coordinate

I'm a beginner in Astronomy. What do these latitudinal and longitudinal lines and accompanying hours and degrees represent (in blue: +12h , +11h.. and +45° +60°.. , in orange: +330° , +15°) ?

[image]

Comment: Where does that image come from? When you post other people's work here, you need to give proper attribution.

Comment: Here's a hint; the 315° line goes straight down from overhead to the horizon where it is labeled as "NW" which represents the [cardinal direction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinal_direction) North-West which is of course at the 315° position. The two stars in Ursa Major (the Big Dipper) that run parallel to the blue "11 h" line are known to be an easy way to find the North Star; a line following those two stars towards the open end of the dipper will lead you to it.

Comment: @uhoh thank you, really helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The blue grid shows equatorial coordinates:
right ascension (0h..24h) and declination (-90°..+90°).
Declination is 0° on the celestial equator and ±90° at the celestial poles.
The Sun's right ascension is 0h at the March equinox, 6h at the June solstice, etc.

The orange grid shows horizontal coordinates:
altitude (-90°..+90°) and azimuth (0°..360°).
Altitude is 0° on the horizon and +90° at the zenith.
Geographic north is azimuth 0°, east is azimuth 90°, etc.